# How To Detect If WPF ComboBox Is In EditMode

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm writing a .NET 4.5 C# / WPF app where I must specifically detect if a `ComboBox` is in edit mode. In other words, I need to know only if the mouse cursor is active and blinking in the editable portion of the `ComboBox`, and the `ComboBox` is ready for input from the user's typing on the keyboard.

I've tried "`TextBoxBase.GotFocus`", "`TextBoxBase.GotKeyboardFocus`", etc.

These events fire even when a user simply clicks on the `ComboBox`, which doesn't make any sense (why does a "`GotKeyboardFocus`" event fire even when I haven't even touched the keyboard?).

Anyways, how can I detect ONLY when the mouse cursor is active and blinking in the editable portion of the `ComboBox`, and the `ComboBox` is ready for input from the user's typing on the keyboard?

Comment: GotKeyboardFocus doesn't mean you touched the keyboard. It means that the control will receive keystrokes. And yes that will start when you click the control/give it focus

Comment: GotFocus and GetCaretIndex

Comment: Got it...

void cmbMyComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
         var obj = (ComboBox)sender;
         if (obj != null)
         {
            var t = (TextBox)obj.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", obj);
            if (t != null) 
            {
               t.MaxLength = 16;
               t.GotFocus += (s, a) => { //my code } };
               t.LostFocus += (s, a) => { //my code } };
            }
         }
      }

Answer (score 0):

Got it...

```
void cmbMyComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var obj = (ComboBox)sender;
   if (obj != null)
   {
      var t = (TextBox)obj.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", obj);
      if (t != null)
      {
         t.MaxLength = 16;
         t.GotFocus += (s, a) => { MyFunction(); } };
         t.LostFocus += (s, a) => { MyOtherFunction(); } };
      }
   }
}
```